# My DVD drive isn't recognized by Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, hardware-failure

My DVD drive is recognized at the BIOS, and I can access it before Windows starts.  Once Windows starts, the optical drive is no longer recognized.  I have found solutions on the internet that involve editing my registry, but I have no experience doing this.  In fact, what I can find on the internet pertaining to editing the Windows Registry actually makes me quite nervous about editing it myself.  I'm not sure what exactly is causing my problem, but are there any other solutions for issues like this that do not involve me editing my registry?

Comment: Where registry keys were you supposed to change? You say it **may** not be found, what does that mean?

Comment: If the registry script is suggested by Microsoft or some other source you trust simply backup your system then run the registry script.

Answer (score 0):

This is not *THE* solution, but it relates to *a* solution, and most likely the one you alluded to (without actually linking to).

You see, certain programs leave behind and/or install filters that alter the operational status of your optical drives.  Although you are frightened of editing your registry hive manually, you can allow Microsoft to do it for you.

[Follow this link to this Microsoft article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/982116).  It not only provides a link to an autmatic fix, but if you choose to, it also tells you the manual steps you can follow, should you decide to dive into your own registry.

Again, I want to repeat, you do not have to edit your own registry.  You can simply click the green RUN NOW button.